# Bootstrap sidebar on each side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to create a webpage that has fixed responsive columns on each side of the main content.

The code I currently have works with bootstrap until I get it down to sm then the center content goes on top of the sidebars.

Comment: Noone can help you if you don't show us any code.

Comment: Use the col-xs-* classes instead of the col-sm-* classes, these don't 'stack' at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.centerDiv {

    position : relative;
    left: (width of the left div);
}
```

For example if the width of left div is 200px, then give left: 200px;